# How to separate development and production environments in Azure?

Tags: azure, credentials

My company process sensitive data and needs to restrict access to production environment. How do I organize subscriptons and (storage) accounts so that I have separate environments?

I could have completely distinct subscriptions but I want to give some devs the power to deploy on production while others should only have access to development assets.

In my ideal world, I'd add individuals to security groups. Whenever a thw dev wants to deploy on production, he/she would use his/her credentials plus an extra confirmation step, like an otp. This way I'd avoid mistakes but still keep simple users management. Is that possible in azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually what you are wanting to do will be possible, and is possible to some degree depending on the resource. As more of the features of Azure make it into the preview portal (portal.azure.com) they are showing up with [Role Based Access Controls](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/), which is what you are looking for.  Unfortunately, right now not all of the resources are there and some are there without full RBAC baked in (such as storage accounts).

For now, the best bet is to still separate by subscription. If you need developers to have the ability to perform a deployment you can create a script that performs the deployment (using stored PowerShell credentials or secured management certs) and then give the developers the ability to execute the script.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you need a storage account for production and a storage account for development. I would also suggest giving a lead developer responsibilities for managing deployments to the production environment. All other developers would have access to the dev storage account for testing, but would then have to coordinate with the lead developer for actual deployment of any addition of queue, or uploading of blobs.

As far as deployments of the build itself you could add pipelines to automate everything and then add an approval step on the production slot. That way two developers can decide when something can make it to production. Any slot swapping etc would be done through a pipeline instead of through any UI's.

You could setup the storage account to be protected via firewall so any developer that is meant to have access is added manually through whitelisting IP's. I don't know if introducing more resources makes sense in your situation, but could serve as an alternative if you only want one subscription